# OS/2: Bad sxHeight settig it to 0: -1

Tags: firefox, fonts, console

I am seeing a console error with my font.  It is a custom font and has so far worked well (and indeed still renders normally).  In Mozilla Firefox I am now seeing this error:

```
downloadable font: OS/2: Bad sxHeight settig it to 0: -1 (font-family: "alte_din_1451_mittelschriftRg" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: https://www.xxxxxxx/templates/g5_hydrogen/custom/fonts/din-alte/din1451alt-webfont.woff2
```

Does anyone know what this error means and whether there is any way to save this warning?  I'd hate to have to suddenly change the font at this stage, the error seems to be a new thing.  The error does not appear in Chrome.

Comment: it means literally what it says: the OS/2 table has the value "-1" for the sxHeight field, which is [a nonsense value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#sxheight). OTS (the validator used by Firefox and Chrome) is constantly getting updated, so it's only not appearing in Chrome _yet_. It will. Fix the font, or what whoever made it fix it instead. And as this is a woff2, first check whether the _original_ font has a correct sxHeight value. If so, no need to fix anything, just generate a new woff2.

Comment: Oh man, it's not my font.  I don't predict it will be updated either.  This derails my project somewhat just before completion.  How annoying.  Is it easy to edit a font file?  It had a lot of strange values when I tried.

Comment: Easy? Very. Legal? Almost certainly not, but you'll have to find the actual license for this font (I'm seeing a lot of "free" copies on highly questionable font sites, all of which mention an typeface author who has no homepage, and that's definitely not how people who make typefaces roll. If you can't find the official original, _especially_ if it's a paid project, find a properly licensed substitute. Or find the original source if you can)

Comment: (and maybe ask around on https://typedrawers.com)

Comment: I picked it because I thought it was free.  I found information on Font Squirrel indicating that.  I'll ask around on the site you have suggested.  Thank you Mike.

Comment: Font websites are not themselves the authority when it comes to what a font's license is. Font theft is so prevalent that only an official release license can be trusted (as well as licensing businesses like typekit etc.) In this case, https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?q%5Bterm%5D=1451&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y does not list any font so it sounds like that's not where you got it. Datto's "D-DIN", however, is listed, and is a typical free substitute. Remember to read its license to know what you may and may not do with it, and what your obligations are when using it.